# How to keep the current HTML content on my page after refresh? (which solutions are currently the most used?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to keep the current HTML content on my page after refresh? (which solutions are currently the most used?)

I have simple HTML page, and a JavaScript function that loads dynamically HTML controls in my page when a button is clicked. But, after refresh all those added controls are lost. How do I keep them after refresh?

Thank you

Comment: don't refresh - use AJAX and keep the page content throughout

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you're needing to save the user's settings to some sort a database, so when the page is 'refreshed', you can then use Ajax to load the saved controls back onto the page.

Comment: yes I do use AJAX to load html file from server. But the problem then is, how to keep the new html that was added to my page, after refresh?

Comment: user1661677: I am reading about other technologies, maybe Web Storage is better than using a database?

Comment: I highly recommend localStorage for this usage. You can set key:value pairs up and simply repopulate any fields you need to return on a refresh. It will allow you to save information for a refresh and not need a db.

See this page for information on how to use localStorage
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/